# Difference between auto_now and auto_now_add

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

What I understood in `Django` models field's attributes is

- `auto_now` - updates the value of field to current time and date every time the Model.save() is called.
- `auto_now_add` - updates the value with the time and date of creation of record.

My question is what if a filed in model contains both the `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` set to True? What happens in that case?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`auto_now` takes precedence (obviously, because it updates field each time, while `auto_now_add` updates on creation only). Here is the code for [`DateField.pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateField) method:

```
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    if self.auto_now or (self.auto_now_add and add):
        value = datetime.date.today()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
        return value
    else:
        return super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

As you can see, if `auto_now` is set or both `auto_now_add` is set and the object is new, the field will receive current day.

The same for [`DateTimeField.pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/fields/#DateTimeField):

```
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    if self.auto_now or (self.auto_now_add and add):
        value = timezone.now()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
        return value
    else:
        return super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

Answer (score 10):

According to the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateTimeField) using both `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` in your model fields as `True` will result in an error because they are both mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 10):

These fields are built into Django for expressly this purpose — auto_now fields are updated to the current timestamp every time an object is saved and are therefore perfect for tracking when an object was last modified, while an auto_now_add field is saved as the current timestamp when a row is first added to the database and is therefore perfect for tracking when it was created.

Answer (score 6):

As Official Django documentation says -

`auto_now`, `auto_now_add` and `default` are mutually exclusive and will result in an error if used together

Answer (score 1):

If a filed in a model contains both the **auto_now** and **auto_now_add** set to **True** will result in an error like this:

ERRORS:
appname.Model.field_name: (fields.Efield_number) The options auto_now, auto_now_add, and default are mutually exclusive. Only one of these options may be present.