# Django auto_now vs auto_now_add

Tags: django, django-models

Problems are encountered if `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` are confused. How do `auto_now` or `auto_now_add` work?

`auto_now` : Time will be created every time when use `models.save()` or `models.create()` but it doesn't work if you use `query.update()`, it only updates some data but it does not update date automatically

`auto_now_add` : Time will be created only the first time when using `models.save()` or `models.create()`

How should they be used?

`auto_now_add` should be used with `created_date` and `auto_now` should used with `updated_date`

```
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

Comment: Please help to check this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389042/difference-between-auto-now-and-auto-now-add

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a question. I've tried to make the English more grammatical, but it appears to be a self-answered question.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question: how to best use `auto_now_add` vs `auto_now`? - Your ideas for using them with DateTimeField or DateField are exactly right!

`auto_now_add` is perfect for a one-off modification of a field on your model, **ONLY** when the model instance is created and saved for the first time. As you noted, it is great for a `created_at` or `timestamp` field will never need to change again.

`auto_now` is awesome for whenever you need a field to change anytime the .save() method is called on the model instance. `updated_at` would be a great opportunity for this, as you mentioned.

The 2 are mutually exclusive, however, as noted in [Difference between auto_now and auto_now_add](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389042/difference-between-auto-now-and-auto-now-add) - so don't create a model field and pass both arguments!

Your assumptions were sound; just wanted to confirm them :)