# How to set value of DateTime field automatically in Django REST Framework HTML form?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a very basic Django Model and use it in Django REST Framework.

When using the browsable API tool and requesting an instance of a ressource, I can set the values of the different attributes using the HTML form at the bottom of the page. All attributes have their current value pre-set except for the DateTime fields. Is there a special setting required such that the form fields for DateTime entries field are prefilled with their current value?

Model class:

```
class C(models.Model):

    OrderDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False)

    p1 = models.ForeignKey(PA, related_name="cs", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    p2 = models.ForeignKey(PB, related_name="cs", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['OrderDate']
```

View:

```
class CViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset         = C.objects.all().order_by('-OrderDate')
    serializer_class = CSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        cs = C.objects.all()
        # Some filters...
        return cs
```

Serializer:

```
class CSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    p1 = PASerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    p2 = PBSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = C
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'OrderDate',
            'p1',
            'p2',
        )
```

I tried to generalize the code hope the general idea is clear.

I would like that the `OrderDate` field is prefilled with the current value when the HTML form in the browsable API is shown.

Comment: Please add your model, serializer and view to your question

Answer (score 3):

in DateTimeField you have 2 options, add a **default** value or use **auto_now_add**.

in your situation you have set **auto_now**, and according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51389042/difference-between-auto-now-and-auto-now-add)

> **auto_now** - updates the value of field to current time and date every time the Model.save() is called.

> **auto_now_add** - updates the value with the time and date of creation of record.

so you have this two possibilities:

```
OrderDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

or

```
OrderDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is work if you want to automatically add the current time when a user submit the form without displaying it in your HTML, if you want to display the current date and time in html field (your Form), then you have to set it in the frontend side using JavaScript and HTML

```
Use:  <input type="datetime-local">
```

Comment: Thanks, its fine using `auto_date_add`. However, my question initially was that I wanted to have the DateTime form field populated with the current value in the browsable API HTML form. If you know how that is possible, it would be great. Your frontend idea is not quite what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to django drf and had the same problem, and this solved it. (`DATETIME_FORMAT` in `settings.py`)
my guess is because when rendering the html it uses a different format than the one DRF uses

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 
    'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    'DATETIME_FORMAT' : '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M',
}
```